# Getting the Position of listview item onTextChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a restaurant menu in list view, each row in the list view has:

- an image of item
- name of item
- price of item
- edit text to enter quantity
- checkbox to select item

To cater i have a MenuItem object class with the properties mentioned above.

I have implemented custom adapter for the listview. Now i need to implement onTextChangedListener on the EditText, so that whenever the quantity is changed, my object gets updated and therefore is reflected in the final order bill. I have set the default quantity to be 1.

**My adapter class**

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> {

private Context context;

 public MenuAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MenuItem> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        try{

            android.view.LayoutInflater inflator = android.view.LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            View customView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itemdetail, parent, false);

            MenuItem singleItem = getItem(pos);
            //ImageView iconImg = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imgMenuItem);
            TextView nameTxt = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            EditText qtyDdl = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.inputQty);
            TextView priceTxt = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
            CheckBox selectChk = (CheckBox)customView.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);

            nameTxt.setText(singleItem.getName());
            qtyDdl.setText("1");
            qtyDdl.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
                    {@Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                    int i = start;  


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }});
            priceTxt.setText(singleItem.getPrice());

            selectChk.setOnCheckedChangeListener((SaltnPepperActivity)context);

            return customView;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MenuAdapter", e.toString());
        return null;}
    }
```

}

Q1: How do i get the position of the row that is being changed in the view whenever a textchanged happens?
Q2: Do i need to implement onTextChangedListener in the Activity class? If so, again how do i get the position of the item clicked in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the idea from Hahn and this is what I did inside getView function

```
@Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        try{

            android.view.LayoutInflater inflator = android.view.LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            final View customView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itemdetail, parent, false);

            final MenuItem singleItem = getItem(pos);
            //ImageView iconImg = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imgMenuItem);
            TextView nameTxt = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            final EditText qtyDdl = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.inputQty);
            TextView priceTxt = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
            CheckBox selectChk = (CheckBox)customView.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);

            nameTxt.setText(singleItem.getName());
            qtyDdl.setText("1");

            qtyDdl.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
                    {@Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                    //pos is the item clicked   
                        //activity.SetQuantity(customView.getId(), s);
                        try{
                        singleItem.setQty(Integer.parseInt(qtyDdl.getText().toString()));
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e){}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }});
            priceTxt.setText(singleItem.getPrice());

            selectChk.setOnCheckedChangeListener((SaltnPepperActivity)context);

            return customView;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MenuAdapter", e.toString());
        return null;}
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the Edittext "qtyDdl" final in the `getView()` method-callback, and then set the position as the following:
`qtyDdl.setTag(pos)`

After this, you should be able to get the position from the textChangeListener by calling `Integer.parseInt(qtyDdl.getTag().toString());`

Comment: My textChangeListener is also present inside the getview method. Is it correct or should it be defined in the activity? where the listview control is present.?

Comment: Thanks its help me